# Join more than two tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 4 tables and i want to join there tables together in codeigniter. Is it possible with codeigniters join method?

Comment: Just use the join method more than once.  It will join each table.

Comment: @Rocket:Will you please give an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using CodeIgniter's [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) class, you can just use the `join` method multiple times to join multiple tables.

```
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.ID = table1.ID');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table3.ID = table1.ID');
$this->db->join('table4', 'table4.ID = table1.ID', 'left');
```

Comment: This one I expected.Let me check with this

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about joining SQL database tables, is this correct?
If so you can always use the CodeIgniter SQL method, see: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: There really shouldn't be an issue using CI's ActiveRecord join method here either. I'm guessing he's not put any effort into this yet.

Comment: I tried with the query method. And its working fine. But I want to know is it possible with the join method?