# Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list', Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, join

I've been looking at this error for a while and can't see what I'm doing wrong with my codeigniter sql query, can anyone advise?

**Unknown column 'album_images.album_id' in 'field list'**

```
        $this->db->select('
        albums.id as album_id,
        albums.album_title,
        album_images.album_id,
        album_images.image_id,
        AVG(views.id) as views_id,
        views.views as views_total,
        images.id, 
        images.alpha_id,
        images.user,
        images.image_title,
        images.image_type,
        images.file_ext,
        images.image_width,
        images.image_height,
        images.file_size,
        images.submitted,
        images.status'
    );

    $this->db->from('images', 'albums', 'album_images', 'views');
    $this->db->join('albums', 'albums.id = album_images.album_id');
    $this->db->join('views', 'views.id = images.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('albums.id', $id);
    $this->db->where('images.status', 1); //fiter out deleted ones

    $this->db->group_by('images.id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

I've checked all the spelling of everything multiple times and still get the same result. I did try reordering the this->db->from line, moving album_images to the beginning made the error change to images.id instead. If that's relevant at all.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: Can you print the exact error that you receive?

Comment: Where was the error prior to moving album_images?

Comment: You can also `die($this->db->last_query());` to see what the query actually is - maybe it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Jeff here's the exact error http://pastebin.com/V3JgJ9iA

Comment: @David that's the error with albums_images not moved, if moved the 'album_images.album_id' bold at the top of my post changes to 'images.id'

Comment: I can't say for sure, but try making your `from` line look like this: `$this->db->from('images, albums, album_images, views');` - If that doesn't help, your join may be the issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ... FROM (`images`) JOIN `albums` ON `albums`.`id` = `album_images`.`album_id` ...
```

If you do a join between two tables (`images`, `albums`), you need to formulate the relationship between those two. In your case you do a join between two tables but the relationship is with a third table (`album_images`), so the field is not found.

See as well:

- [How to INNER JOIN 3 tables using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7440371/367456)
- [Join more than two tables in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5743295/367456)
- [Multiple Joins in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4916498/367456)

Comment: Yes, and you've asked for what you're doing wrong. That's what I have pointed out in my answer. Please vote it if it helped you. If you don't know how to join three tables with codeigniter db module, I suggest you ask that as in form of a simple, additional question (or search the web about it - hint: I added some links to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this you give duplicate column name 
i correct it you check whether it works or not

```
$this->db->select('
        albums.id as albums_id,
        albums.album_title,
        album_images.album_id,
        album_images.image_id,
        AVG(views.id) as views_id,
        views.views as views_total,
        images.id, 
        images.alpha_id,
        images.user,
        images.image_title,
        images.image_type,
        images.file_ext,
        images.image_width,
        images.image_height,
        images.file_size,
        images.submitted,
        images.status'
    );
```